# nginx module to set variable value for log module

Tags: c, variables, nginx, module

I want to define an nginx variable, set its value during a request, and use the variable inside a log format.

I am currently implementing a custom module in C (not interested in LUA at the moment).

**Desired flow:**
 1. configure new log format: `log_format my_format '$my_var1';` (nginx.conf)
 2. configure new access log using that format: `access_log /tmp/out my_format` (nginx.conf)
 3. set value during request handler, function from the following type:
 `typedef ngx_int_t (*ngx_http_handler_pt)(ngx_http_request_t *r);`

**Current flow:**
1. Set variable to an initial value: `set $my_var1 'empty_value';`  (nginx.conf)
2. Find variable by index with `ngx_http_get_flushed_variable(r, index)`
3. Change variable value by assigning to data field.

When I print my variable to the debug log, I see the variable is set correctly to the changed value. **However**, the log module outputs the initial variable value instead of the changed value to the custom access log.

Can someone point me to what am I missing here?
Should I use `ngx_http_add_variable` function or use script compile /complex ?

short snippet from the current flow described above:

```
ngx_http_variable_value_t *v;
v = ngx_http_get_flushed_variable(r, ale_srv_cf->output_variable_index);
// ... error handling if not found ....
v->data = new_value;
v->len = new_value_length;
```

Comment: Not sure if one module can call another module, if it can then probably you need to call `ngx_stream_log_flush` https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/4bf4650f2f10f7bbacfe7a33da744f18951d416d/src/stream/ngx_stream_log_module.c#L110? or something

Comment: Tarun, I did not mention such connection of module calling another module. my module only sets the value of a variable

Comment: Got it, i misread and though you are changing the log format itself.

Comment: I think this may be the right way to do it? https://github.com/peter-leonov/ngx_http_js_module/blob/f23bb6647f9beb491b23aad8afe43e6a83a1b582/src/classes/Request/Variables.c#L278

Comment: @TarunLalwani, unfortuently I still can't get it working, as both _ngx_hash_find()->data_ which is used to use in the module you suggested , and _ngx_http_get_variable()_ which I used originally, return a pointer to the same  _ngx_http_variable_value_t_ struct. So it seems that no matter which way I use to get this struct, assigning to it, still doesn't work. wdyt?
Any other idea maybe ?

Comment: Did you use the `v->set_handler(r, value, v->data);` i think that is the main thing?

Comment: v->set_handler is NULL from some reason...
 v is set  by
`ngx_hash_find(&cmcf->variables_hash, hash_key, output_variable_name, len);`

I also copied entire set_variable function from the js module, and it only enters to _NGX_HTTP_VAR_INDEXED_ branch

Comment: set_handler is usually null for parameters that can't be updated, can you check if it has the right flags which shows the variable is updatable?

Comment: @TarunLalwani v->flags value is 21; CHANGEABLE, INDEXED, WEAK.

just to clarify, I did not set configure this variable with the _add_variable()_, but by setting it with the _set_ directive from _nginx.conf_.

Comment: it seems that it's not necessary that the set_handler needs to be invoked, in case variable is indexed   https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/blob/master/src/ngx_http_lua_variable.c#L177